# was flatness really used in this argument? (Matsumura, Theorem 7.2)

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a ring and $M$ an $A$-module. Then $M$ is faithfully flat over $A$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $M$ is flat over $A$ and $M \otimes N=0 \Rightarrow N=0$. This is part of theorem 7.2, p. 47 in Matsumura's Commutative Ring Theory.

Let's consider the direction $\Leftarrow$. Matsumura says, "let $N'\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} N \stackrel{g} \rightarrow N''$ be a sequence of $A$-modules and suppose $M \otimes N'\stackrel{f_M}{\rightarrow} M \otimes N \stackrel{g_M} \rightarrow M \otimes N''$ is exact. Then $g_M \circ f_M=(g \circ f)_M=0$ so that BY FLATNESS, $Im(g \circ f) \otimes M= Im(g_M \circ f_M)=0$."

Question: where was it that flatness was used in Matsumura's last deduction? Is it not immdediate by definition (independently of flatness) that $Im(g \circ f) \otimes M= Im(g_M \circ f_M)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flatness is needed to ensure that $-\otimes M$ commutes with taking images.  If $M$ isn't flat, there are a module $B$ and a submodule $A$ such that the inclusion map $i:A\to B$ fails to remain monic when tensored with $M$.  Then the image of $i$ is $A$ (or, more precisely, $i$) itself, and tensoring with $M$ gives $A\otimes M$.  But the image of $i_M$ is a proper quotient of $A\otimes M$, because $i_M:A\otimes M\to B\otimes M$ isn't monic.

Comment: A higher-level view of the situation is that the notion of image (of a map $f$) is defined by factoring $f$ as an epimorphism followed by a monomorphism.  So for a functor to "obviously" preserve images, you'd want it to preserve both epimorphisms (which $-\otimes M$ does in any case) and monomorphisms (which needs flatness).